# How to update correct list item in unordered list on bootstrap modal pop up submission

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have unordered list of messages where each message within list item is clickable.

```
<ul id="home-message-list" class="messages">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="linkClick" name="message"><a href="#">Hi, How are you?</a></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="linkClick" name="message"><a href="#">Hi, How are you?</a></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Everytime `<span class="linkClick"><a href="#">Hi, How are you?</a></span>` is clicked I handle it using ajax class based on `.linkClick`, and open a bootstrap modal pop-up. Reason I do it this way is to be able to dynamically populate the content of modal.

```
$('.linkClick').click(function(){
      $.get( "/loadModal")
       .done(function(data) {
          $('#message-model-content').html(data);
          $('#messageModal').modal('show');
       });
 });
```

I want to update message in relevant list item from which modal was opened after response from server.

I can handle the reply from modal pop-up but not sure how to update correct list item. I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn_sendMessageReply", function(){ 
        $.getJSON('/sendReply', {
        }, function(data) {
            $('#messageModal').modal('hide');
            $(this).closest("li").find("span[name='message']").text(data);
        }); 
      });
```

I have tried this `$("span[name='message']").text(data);` but it updated both list

How can I update correct list item from which modal pop up was opened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be losing context for `$(this)` before your AJAX request completes. Try using a temporary variable to keep the context.

**Your code:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn_sendMessageReply", function() {
  $.getJSON('/sendReply', {}, function(data) {
    $('#messageModal').modal('hide');
    $(this).closest("li").find("span[name='message']").text(data);
  });
});
```

**Change to:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn_sendMessageReply", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $.getJSON('/sendReply', {}, function(data) {
    $('#messageModal').modal('hide');
    $this.closest("li").find("span[name='message']").text(data);
  });
});
```

---

*Edit per discussion in comments below:*

Here's another way to keep a reference to the current relevant row, by adding a class to it.

```
$('.linkClick').click(function() {
  $('.linkClick.active').removeClass('active'); // clear the active row (if there is one)
  $(this).addClass('active'); // make this the active row
  $.get("/loadModal")
    .done(function(data) {
      $('#message-model-content').html(data);
      $('#messageModal').modal('show');
    });
});

$(document).on("click", "#btn_sendMessageReply", function() {
  $.getJSON('/sendReply', {}, function(data) {
    $('#messageModal').modal('hide');
    $('.linkClick.active').text(data); // active row gets new text
  });
});
```

Comment: Still the same. Nothing happens. no errors. Seems it can't find li with that span name

Comment: @jas We don't have enough of your HTML here to determine the problem, then. Is `#btn_sendMessageReply` within that `li` element? Otherwise using `.closest()` won't help to find it.

Comment: No, it is not. modal is outside of li element and just shown using ajax call. I think that's where the problem is. Is there anyway to know from which li element modal pop was called?

Comment: @jas You can save a reference to the current `.linkClick` row by appending a class. I've updated my answer above to show how to easily do this.

Comment: That's works! One stupid question. I don't much about jquery. Is there anyway to keep href. Doing this way href goes away. It is better for visual clues that this link is clickable

Comment: @jas Using `<a href="#">` elements purely to simulate link styles is poor practice. You can accomplish the same with CSS: `.linkClick { color: blue; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline; }`

Comment: Great. Learned something new :)